# Bootstrap - Align Properly

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my page

```
<div class="well">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2 pull-right">
                Hi | <span class="label label-info">Player</span> | <a href=""><span class="label label-danger">Logout</span></a><br><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-7">
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Link 1 with big text </a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Link2 oktext</a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Linked text3</a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Linked text4</a>
                <br><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><br/>

</div>
```

[Bootply with output](http://bootply.com/82828)
The problem i'm facing is, i can't make the `buttons` (`linked text4`)and `logout` label align in a straight line even though i've used the `pull-right` and `offset`.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your pull-right is on the wrong element. It pulls the col-sm-2 and the col-lg-7 to the right as it should. To get the content of a div to the right you have to do `text-right`.
Its easy to analyze with chrome dev tools.

```
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2 text-right pull-right">
                Hi | <span class="label label-info">Player</span> | <a href=""><span class="label label-danger">Logout</span></a><br><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-7 pull-right text-right">
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Link 1 with big text </a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Link2 oktext</a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Linked text3</a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Linked text4</a>
                <br><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

http://bootply.com/82835

As I see now, there is still a slightly difference, thats because `.label` has an em padding and the btn-sm has an absolute padding. You have to switch to buttons for both or fix the padding via your custom.css, but this could mess up other label related displays.